# Can a spectral image speak?

Tags: dnd-4e

D&D 4th Ed says the mage spell Spectral Image creates a "complex illusion of a creature or object" that can "make sounds".

Can a spectral image speak?  If so, can the mage control its dialog if within range?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Spectral image is written as:

> Effect: The illusion of a creature or an object up to Medium size appears in an unoccupied square within range. **It can make sounds** and can move within its square, but it cannot leave it.

As it can make 'sounds', and there's no specific ruling against it, I would rule that mage would indeed be able to control it's dialogue.

Your DM may rule that 'sounds' doesn't necessarily mean 'speech'

Comment: That is indeed what the DM ruled - "make sounds" isn't speech, but I appreciate it's up to interpretation.  Thanks.

Comment: If it can't at least moan and make chain-rattling noises, I petition to have the spell renamed.